# Google Script Protection Issues with disjoint Ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Array of Ranges that I am trying to loop through to protect, but it is not working anymore. I do not know why. It was working yesterday just fine, but the protections are not happening on the sheet. I have tried removing all editors, but we are still able to edit. Basically, I have a sheet of Named ranges; I create an array based on those ranges; then get a rangelist from that array; I then loop through the rangelist to protect each range.

```
function protectTU(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Named Ranges");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of TRUCK UPDATES");
    var lr1 = s1.getRange("A3:A").getValues(); //Find last rowv
    var lr2 = lr1.filter(String).length; //Find last row
    var lr3 = parseInt(lr2) - 1;
    var data1 = s1.getRange("A3:E" + lr2).getValues();
    var dis = 2;
    var i = 1;
    var v1 = [];


    for (var j = i; j < lr3 - 1; j++)
    {


        if(data1[j][4] == dis)
        {
           v1.push(data1[j][1]);
        }

        if(dis == 1 && j == 43)
        {break;}
        if(dis == 2 && j == 81)
        {break;}
        if(dis == 3 && j == 135)
        {break;}


    }

    var ranges = s2.getRangeList(v1); 

    **for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++)
    {
        var protection = ranges[i].protect().setDescription('Please see the office for permission');
    }**


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I would like to see an image of your spreadsheet and some data to confirm so this is pretty much a guess.

```
function protectTU(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Named Ranges");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of TRUCK UPDATES");
  var lr3 = s1.getRange(3,1,s1.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues();//better not to use A1Notation for setting up range here 
  var data1 = s1.getRange(3,1,s1.getLastRow()-2,5).getValues();//and here
  var dis = 2;
  var i = 1;
  var v1 = [];
  for (var j=0;j<data1.length;j++) {
    if(data1[j][4] == dis) {
      v1.push(data1[j][1]);//so hopefully column2 has A1Notation
    }
    if(dis==1 && j==43){break;}
    if(dis==2 && j==81){break;}
    if(dis==3 && j==135){break;}
  }
  var ranges = s2.getRangeList(v1).getRanges();
  //I don't use protection much so  I don't know about this
  for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++){
    var protection = ranges[i].protect().setDescription('Please see the office for permission');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a basic version of the spreadsheet. The answer above helped a lot by the way, but it is still too slow. The answer was what I needed. Now I have to fix that. So my people are divided by truck numbers. However, there is one person that has random numbers. I cannot lock a huge chunk at time because another editor needs to edit their trucks too.

So I need to Lock the rows for trucks 301/302/303/305/310.. while not locking the numbers in between them which is why I have to loop it. I need to be able to lock out one person at a time. The divisions are 1:301-350, 2:351-394, 3:395-335..., 4:Random numbers.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HJROXH1fhkSMtdgQQqUUrKxi0hj7s42I9rjCoz-Vswc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So I gather that you had to modify this `v1.push(data1[j][1]);` to something like this: `v1.push(ss.getRangeByName(data1[j][1]).getA1Notation());`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with protection because I hardly ever use use it.  Do each one of your people in different truck have access to the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was s2.getRangeList(v1).***GETRANGES()*** part.

So, everyone views the same spreadsheet, but if I need for x person to see me urgently I want to be able to freeze what they are doing until they see me. Additionally everyone can keep working on their portion of the spreadsheet.